# scapy ntp v4 monlist packet

Tags: scapy, ntp

```
>>> packet = IP(dst="ntpid")/UDP(dport=123,sport=50000)/("\x1b\x00\x00\x00"+"\x00"*11*4)
>>> packet.show()

###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = None
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = None
  id        = 1
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = None
  src       = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  dst       = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
     sport     = 50000
     dport     = ntp
     len       = None
     chksum    = None
###[ Raw ]### 
        load      = '\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

>>> rep,non_rep = sr(packet)
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
..........................^C
Received 26 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

I would like to get the ntp_monlist response of my NTP server.
Actually the packet is sent but I didn't receive anything.
Can someone tell me the reason?

I try for it like this？ But the received ntp is question mark。

```
 >>> packet = IP(dst=ntpserver)/UDP(dport=123,sport=50000)/ NTP(version=4)
    >>>rep,non_rep = sr(packet)
    >>> rep.show()
    0000 IP / UDP / NTP v??, ?? ==> IP / UDP / NTP v??, ??
```

Comment: It could be many things, from a cable issue to an access-list; not enough info here to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the following command:

```
data  = "\x17\x00\x03\x2a" + "\x00" * 4
send(IP(src=src_ip, dst=dst_ip)/UDP(sport=RandShort(),dport=123)/Raw(load=data),count=packets_chunk)
```

Source: https://vulners.com/packetstorm/PACKETSTORM:127492